# RequireJS and Headless Test-Driven Development

Tags: javascript, tdd, requirejs

I'm looking to use RequireJS for my next big JS project however I am having a hard time figuring out how to test for it in a headless testing environment. I'm new to both RequireJS and the test-driven approach to coding so anything that is noob friendly would be great.

Comment: I didn't know the term headless before Googling it just now, so I might be getting this wrong, but I have a hard time seeing what your choice of module loader has to do with your tests. Also, test-driven development is usually done with unit tests, whereas from what I can tell the "headless" adjective is applied mainly to acceptance tests.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to this so if I'm confusing some of the details in my question, I apologize. For headless testing, I've used envjs with Jasmine. Its all unit testing, just from the command line with no browser. Like, with Rhino or Node.

Comment: OK, so does "headless" in this context just mean "no browser"? I guess that makes sense. In that case I think I can try to answer...

Comment: No, wait, I can't, because I still don't understand what the module framework has to do with TDD. Why would you want to "test for [RequireJS]"? Does that mean test for its presence? If so, do you test for jQuery? Still confused :)

Comment: Yes, headless as in no browser. All from the command line.  I'm trying to write test-driven code for my javascript web apps. Since I'm using RequireJS, I'd like to test for that to make sure the modules are loading and all the subsequent events dependent on them are firing correctly. The developer for RequireJS uses Dojox for testing his builds and I'm going through that to see if maybe I can make some sense of it. However, if you have any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here is my thoughts. You should write tests only for your own code, not third party code, so there is no need to test that RequireJS as a library is working correctly. (They have their own tests, which you should trust.)

So you should be able to assume, in your tests, that RequireJS is working. Just like you assume `parseInt` works, and `setTimeout` works, and `Math.min` works: the developers of those have their own tests, and you don't need to write more.

If it's not working (quite unlikely), or if you are using it incorrectly (marginally more likely), then your test should fail catastrophically: you will end up calling methods on objects that don't exist, for example.

With this in mind, you should unit test your individual RequireJS modules. To do this, either each test fixture should be enclosed in a module that `require`s its system-under-test module, or tests should be asynchronous, and as part of them they should `require` the system-under-test-module. Again, just assume you got the correct module back: if you didn't, i.e. if you are misusing RequireJS, the tests will fail catastrophically.

Comment: So instead of testing the mechanism that uses RequireJS to pull in modules and then writing tests to check those modules, I could just use whatever method that is available in the test suite to load those modules and then go from there. Instead testing `require([jsfiles], function() {});` I would use `load(jsfiles); load(jsfiles);` to ensure that my dependencies are there and working correctly. Something like that?

Comment: Well, I would just use RequireJS in your tests. That is, either my text fixture would be a RequireJS module, or each of my tests would have `require([jsfiles], function () { })` in them.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to mock it without having to include the require statement in the test. That way I don't have to change two places if I ever need to require the js files that I need to require. However, this has got me pointed in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Again, I feel you should only mock `require` if you mock `Math.min`, `setTimeout`, et al.: you should view it as part of your "standard library".

Answer (score 5):

You can test RequireJS modules from the command line [using r.js to run your scripts in Node](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html).

Then, you can use Node modules, like [assert](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/assert.html), to create a test suite for yourself.

Here's an overly simple example:

`scripts/simple.js`:

```
define({ name: 'Really simple module' });
```

`tests/test_simple.js`:

```
require({ baseUrl: 'scripts' }, ['assert', 'simple'], function(assert, simple) {

    var test = function(callback) {
        var msg;
        try {
            callback();
        } catch (e) {
            msg = 'Failed: expected "' + e.expected + 
                  '" but got "' + e.actual + '" instead.';
        }
        if (!msg) {
            msg = 'Passed';
        }
        console.log(msg);
    };

    // This will pass
    test(function() {
        assert.equal(simple.name, 'Really simple module');
    });

    // This will fail
    test(function() {
        assert.equal(simple.name, 'Foo');
    });

});
```

Then, you could run the test from the top level directory of your project:

```
node path/to/r.js test/test_simple.js
```

And you could probably do better than that. The assert module is just the bare bones that you need for making yourself a test suite. If you don't want to roll your own, you might try using a package like [CommonJS Test Runner](https://github.com/Gozala/test-commonjs), but be sure to read the [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js) documentation first.